# How does the equation "dW = - (2 * (X^T ).dot(Y - Y_hat)) / m" comes in Linear Regression (using Matrix + Gradient Descent)?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, linear-regression, gradient-descent, linear-algebra

I was trying to code the Linear Regression in Python using Matrix Multiplication method using Gradient Descent and followed a code where there was no mention what is the loss but just a code as **Per Iteration**:

```
y_hat = X.dot(W) + b

dW = - (2 * (X^T ).dot(Y - Y_hat)) / m # how does the minus and matrix multiplications are used instead of Summation?
db = - (2 * np.sum(Y - Y_hat)) / m  # np is numpy

W = W - lr * dW  # update weights
b = b - lr * db
```

I know from the code is that `dW` is derivative of the weight matrix per iteration, `X^T` is the Transpose of the X features, `Y` is original values of `Y` , `Y_hat` are predicted values using the formula `X.dot(W)+b`.

What I want to know is that `dW = - (2 * (X^T ).dot(Y - Y_hat)) / m`. Even with the `MSE` loss, [as given in this link in the equation 1.4](https://mccormickml.com/2014/03/04/gradient-descent-derivation/), it should be something else.

**Can someone please elaborate how are the values of `dW,db` are calculated here?**

[Whole Python Code is giveb here for Linear Regression](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linear-regression-implementation-from-scratch-using-python/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dW` and `db` are simply the derivative of the loss function with regards to the weights and biases. Given the loss function

$J = \frac{1}{m} \Sigma_{i=1}^{m}(y_i - h(x_i))^2$

the derivatives of the loss to the weights (`dW`) and bias are equal to

$\frac{\partial}{\partial W} J = -\frac{2}{m} \Sigma_{i=1}^{m}(y_i - h(x_i)) * x_i$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial b} J = -\frac{2}{m} \Sigma_{i=1}^{m}(y_i - h(x_i))$

As you can see, these equations align with the code you provided. Equation 1.4 from the link you provided is for $\theta_0$, i.e. the bias, which is the same as the code for `db` (with the only difference being the minus sign, causing by the fact that $y_i$ and $h(x_i)$ are swapped in the loss function between the first and second article).

Comment: Oh Yeah1 Got it. Thanks.